# Traceback error in Python for homework assignment

Tags: python

Getting a traceback error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python Codes\Falling Distance\hodge_Lab5b.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\Python Codes\Falling Distance\hodge_Lab5b.py", line 9, in main
    print(get_time, '\t', format(falling_distance, '.2f'))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to function.__format__
```

```
#file 1 named hodge_Lab5b.py
def main():
    from falling_distance import falling_distance
    get_time = int(input("Enter the time, in seconds, the object has been falling: "))
    print("Time",'\t' "Distance")
    print("--------------------------")
    for get_time in range (1,11):
        print(get_time, '\t', format(falling_distance(main), '.2f'))
    return get_time

main()


#File 2 named falling_distance.py

def falling_distance(main):
    gravity = 9.8
    fallingTime = main()
    distance = (1/2)*gravity*(fallingTime**2)
    return distance
```

Cannot figure out how to get these to work together. I do not know what I have done wrong. I have read through the relevant parts on the book several times. I feel like I am overlooking something rather simple and it is just not jumping out at me.

Answer (score 0):

string formatting

old python: `'%s %s' % ('one', 'two')`

new python: `'{} {}'.format('one', 'two')`

also

`for get_time in range(1,11):` will iterate over 1,2,3...10 
you probably want to do sth like this

`for sec_nb in range(1, get_time+1):
    print('falling time: {} \t falling dist: {}'.format(sec_nb, falling_distance(sec_nb)))`

btw you want to pass number to `falling_distance` function, not a function

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a few issues here. Since it's homework, I'm reluctant to provide any code. Here are a couple of issues that I see:

1. Naming. You're passing the function named `main` into the function called `falling_distance`. This is *probably* not what you want to do (definitely not with the provided code). If you carefully rename everything, I'm guessing most of the problems will go away with some extra debugging.
2. Inside calling_distance, you're again calling the function `main` which would seem to put you in an infinite loop. This is related to issue #1, but know that you'll need to revise how you're using the passed parameter in falling distance
3. If you're using python 2, I think you'll run into printing problems when printing out the table results
4. `get_time` is being reassigned in the for loop, which does not seem to be intended. You'll want to replace this with a new variable here
5. If you're using python 2, I expect that your falling_distance function will always return 0. This is because `(1/2)` is going to be interpreted as `0` (due to integer division). You should instead have the division happen last, once you know the numerator.

I see a few other issues as well, plus there are some style and convention issues that are more important long term.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally found to work. Thanks for your help.

```
#file 1
def main():
    print( "Time\tFalling Distance\n-----------------------" )
    from falling_distance import fallingDistance
    for currentTime in range(1,11):
        print(currentTime, "\t", format(fallingDistance(currentTime),\
            ".2f"))
main()

#file 2

def fallingDistance(fallingTime):
    gravity=9.8
    distance=(1/2)*gravity*(fallingTime**2)
    return distance
```

Was certainly naming issues that caused a lot of the problems.

Thank you for your help!